# Combining isset and is_null fails when checking undefined object property

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to combine `isset` and `is_null` in one function for ease of use

My approach:

```
class sys {

  public static function is_null(&$variable) {

    // if it's not set
    if (!isset($variable)) {
      return true;
    }

    // if array
    if (is_array($variable)) {
      return (boolean) (count($variable) < 1);
    }

    // if string
    return (boolean) (strlen($variable) < 1);
  }

}
```

The problem I'm having when i use it within an object is following exception:

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Indirect modification of overloaded property xxx has no effect.

Comment: What PHP Version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ease of use?  The equivalent is `return !isset($var) || empty($var);`.  is that so hard?

The thing that you need to realize when building a function like this, is that `isset()` is **not** a function.  It's a language construct.  So you can't pass a variable to a function, and then call isset on that variable (well, without generating a notice at least).

Secondly, there's no need to cast to boolean in :`return (boolean) (strlen($variable) < 1);`.  It's exactly the same as `return strlen($variable) < 1;`.

Third, there's no reason to `count()` or use `strlen()`, since that's exactly what `empty()` was designed to check for.

Fourth, there's no reason at all to pass the argument by reference.  It won't change anything, and it's needlessly creating references where there's no reason to.  Just take the argument as normal (it won't use any more memory thanks to copy-on-write).

All in all, I would suggest *not* making this sort of "helper" function.  Just use `!isset($var) || empty($var)` if you want to check if it's empty.  It's clearer, makes more semantic sense, and frankly isn't duplicating effort.  And if you don't care about the notice, you can just replace the entire call with `if (empty($variable))`...

But if you do use this kind of function, I'd suggest changing the name.  It will return `true` even if the variable is not `null`, so calling the function `is_null` is down right misleading.  Perhaps `is_empty` would be better...

Comment: just double checked. empty also checks whether a variable is undefined. so empty should suffice

Comment: I'm always careful with empty(), because it also considers the number 0 as empty. That can be or cannot be what n00b wants.

Answer (score 0):

just use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty)